# Learning strings and pointers but confusing results

Tags: arrays, string, void-pointers

I trying to learn about pointers and this code appears to return incorrect values.

```
char start[5]= "1234"; // Auto adds Null Char;
char* p_start;
int i;

int main(){
    printf("Original %s\n",start);
    p_start = start;
    for (i=0; i<4; i++)
    {
    //   start[2]='j';
       printf("Line 1 %c\n",start[i]);
       start[2]='k';
       printf("Line 2 %c\n",p_start[i]);
   }
   return 0;
}

Original 1234
Line 1 1
Line 2 1
Line 1 2
Line 2 2
Line 1 k ----------------  Why is this not 3 
Line 2 k
Line 1 4
Line 2 4
```

If I un-comment start[2]='j'; then I get

```
Original 1234
Line 1 1
Line 2 1
Line 1 2
Line 2 2
Line 1 j Correct
Line 2 k
Line 1 4
Line 2 4
```

So why is the 3 not bring printed ?

Thanks Wallace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<s>you're not copying the strings, p_start and start are the exact same string at the exact same location. modify one and you modify the other. if you want to copy the string, try using `strcpy`</s>

EDIT: Oh you wanted the three printed. well every loop you're setting it to 'k', so on the first iteration its set, but what you're wanting is to set it after its printed the correct one.

try this,

```
if(i == 2)
  start[2] = 'k';
```

Answer (score 0):

p_start and start point to the same memory area.

```
p_start = start;
```

When you execute

```
start[2]='k';
```

you replace the '3' character with 'k'.

So it's correct that when i is equal to 2 is printed 'k' two times.

Answer (score 0):

You are changing value at very first, when i=0. That means before printing 3. even before printing 2. Try to give a condition like below. Pointer is actually pointing address of the variable. You can also understand by the 2nd option. I did not test that but hope that will work.

```
    int main(){
      printf("Original %s\n",start);
      p_start = start;
      for (i=0; i<4; i++)
      {
        printf("Line 1 %c\n",start[i]);
        if(i==2)
           start[2]='k';
        printf("Line 2 %c\n",p_start[i]);
      }
      return 0;
    }
```

or

```
    int main(){
      printf("Original %s\n",start);
      p_start = start;
      printf("Pointer %s\n",p_start);
      start[2]='k';
      printf("Original %s\n",start);
      printf("Pointer %s\n",p_start);
      return 0;
    }
```